# Official javadoc for Sitebricks (0.8.6)

Tags: java, javadoc, sitebricks

Where can I find the official Javadoc for Sitebricks (in my case, version 0.8.6)? There is nothing on neither the [Google Code Page](http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/) nor on [Sitebricks.org](http://sitebricks.org/#home). The closest thing I could find was on Jarvana (http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/doc?search_type=javadoc_project&project=sitebricks), but this is very far from what I am looking for. I want to use something that is **official** from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the official source code from [the repository](https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks) and build the javadoc yourself.

If you use Eclipse you can also just use the zip of the source code and attach that to your library jar. Eclipse will dynamically render the javadoc from source files.

Comment: What if I am using Maven? Will Eclipse still be able to attach the Javadoc?

Comment: Yes. Just place the downloaded (and zipped) source code in some directory that makes sense to you. Then you can attach the source to the library jar.

Answer (score 1):

SiteBricks is not a google product anymore. We'll not get anything official from Google. the repository on github is the home of the project.

https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks

Regards

Comment: Hmm interesting, I didn't know that Sitebricks was no longer Google-owned.

Comment: It is detailed in FAQ section of sitebricks.org
Sitebricks was developed while Dhanji R. Prasanna was at Google working on Google Wave. Portions of it are copyrighted by Google, Inc. There are many contributors who have helped improve Sitebricks over the years, some from Google, and several outside.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadocs are published as part of the Maven release process. You can obtain them from Central.